# To find domian of $\log_{[x-1]}\sin(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have to find the domain of $\log_{[x-1]}\sin(x)$. Now I have

1. $\sin x>0$
2. $[x-1]>0$
3. $[x-1] \neq 1 $

From (2) I get $x \in [2,\infty]$.

From (3) I get $x \in (-\infty,2) \cup (3,\infty)$

I do not know how to take intersection of these with $\sin x>0$. Help will be appreciated.

P.S- **[] DENOTES GREATEST INTEGER FUNCTION**. i am stuck on this
Thanks

Comment: $\sin x>0\iff x\in\bigcup\limits_{k\in\Bbb Z} (2k\pi,2k\pi+\pi)$

Comment: What you got from $(3)$ doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
&\log_{\lceil x-1\rceil}\sin x=\frac{\ln\sin x}{\ln\lceil x-1\rceil},\quad \ln\lceil x-1\rceil\neq0\\
\\
&\ln\lceil x-1\rceil\neq0\\
&\quad\Rightarrow \lceil x-1\rceil\neq1\\
&\quad\Rightarrow x\notin(1,2]\\
\\
&\text{domain of ln} = (0,\infty)\\
&\quad\Rightarrow \sin x, \lceil x-1\rceil\in (0,\infty)\\
&\quad\Rightarrow x\in (0,\pi)\cup(2\pi,3\pi)\cup\ldots\cup(2n\pi,(2n+1)\pi)\\
&\quad\text{or } x\in(0,\infty)
\\
\\
&\Rightarrow x\in\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}(2n\pi,(2n+1)\pi)\,\backslash(1,2]
\end{align}$$